# "Unnecessary cast to float" seems necessary. What am I missing?

Tags: java, netbeans, casting

Netbeans *** 7.4 *** tells me "Unnecessary cast to float" for this line:

```
int points; // EDIT *********************
String word; 

appendOutput(word + 
                  (points > 0 
                  ? "\t" + round((float)points/word.length(),2)  
                  : ""));
```

But if I remove `(float)`, the output is truncated (as it should be under the circumstances) to the greatest integer less than `points/word.length`.

So what's up with Netbeans? If I want correct output to hundredths, I have to ignore its suggestion to remove `(float)`.

Or am I doing something wrong/untasteful or just missing something?

*** EDIT ***

Heh... forgot I wrote my own `round` method:

```
  public static double round(float x, int n){
    return Math.floor((0 + Math.pow(10, n)*x + 0.5)) / Math.pow(10, n);  
  }
```

*** MCVE ***

```
public class JavaApplication66 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int points = 23; // EDIT *********************
    String word = "FOO"; 

    System.out.println(word + 
                (points > 0 
                ? "\t" + round((float)points/word.length(),2)  
                : ""));
}

public static double round(float x, int n){
  return Math.floor((0 + Math.pow(10, n)*x + 0.5)) / Math.pow(10, n);  
}
```

}

** edit ** just added `(float)` to MCVE... augh...

Comment: `points` is type int?

Comment: How have you declared `word` and `points`?

Comment: What is the type of `points`?  What type does `round` take for its first argument?

Comment: It would be nice if you posted a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this warning and your Netbeans version.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Netbeans. I think a minimal example and the Netbeans version is the way to go (as suggested by @Radiodef).

Comment: Regardless of your answers, it sure looks like you should be using `String.format(...)`.

Comment: If you just want to silence the warning, try casting the divisor to float.

Comment: @HotLicks--same message

Comment: Please include the signature of the `round` method in your question.  If the first parameter of that method is of type `float`, the argument will be automatically promoted to float, which would explain the Netbeans warning.

Comment: For completeness, what is this `round()` method you're calling? It doesn't look like `Math.round()`.

Comment: @VGR: but it would promote **after** the division took place, so I disagree -- it wouldn't explain the problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah, I see your point.  The cast applies only to `points`, not the result of the division.  So yes, this does look like a bug in Netbeans.

Comment: e.g., `System.out.printf("%-7s %.2f%n", word, (double) points / word.length());`

Comment: I hope everyone noticed all the edits I made to fill in the gaps pointed out in comments above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels--Thanks for suggestion, but it, too, raised warning. However, this worked: `System.out.printf("%-7s %.2f%n", word, 1.0* points / word.length());`

Comment: Your MCVE doesn't have the cast in it, that I can see.

Comment: My gosh... OK... now it DOES.......

Comment: @Hovercraft--FYI: `System.out.printf("%-7s%-5s%n", word, 
                points > 0 
                ? String.format("" + round(1.0f * points/word.length(),2))  
                : "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis of what we know, I don't think you're missing anything. It looks like a bug in Netbeans.

Since `(float)` binds to `points` and not to the result of the division, the cast alters the semantics of the program and can't be reasonably described as "unnecessary".

An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help confirm this (and would be useful when filing a bug report).

Comment: I just edited in a MCVE, but I can't say that I know how to file a bug report, if you're suggesting that I should. I'll Google to see how, but feel free to do it yourself, if you want.

Comment: @NPE--I tried to submit a bug report, but it looks like it's possible this has been fixed in 8.0, so I couldn't justify going on, since I really didn't know what I was doing.

Comment: My guess is that the analyzer misinterprets the code and believes that `(float)` binds to the whole expression.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `points` is `int`, then this:

```
points / word.length()
```

Is an `int` division, so the result will be an `int`. If the result has a decimal part, it will be rounded down to fit in an `int`.

The type casting to `float` or `double` for one of the operands is necessary if you want/need a `float` or `double` result.

From what the code looks like, there's no bug and no warning should raise. This seems like a bug in Netbeans. With the proper signature of `round` method this can be proven by testing similar code with javac or using another IDE like Eclipse or Intellij.

---

With the implementation of `round` method, I wrote this example to reproduce the problem in Eclipse and Intellij.

```
public class Test {
    public static double round(float x, int n){
        return Math.floor((0 + Math.pow(10, n)*x + 0.5)) / Math.pow(10, n);  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int points = 0;
        String word = "foo";
        StringBuilder appendOutput = new StringBuilder();
        appendOutput.append(word + 
            (points > 0 
                ? "\t" + round((float)points/word.length(),2)  
                : ""));
    }
}
```

None of these IDEs raised a warning, so looks like a bug in Netbeans.

Comment: While all of this is true, it's doesn't address the question.

Comment: I realize all that; why is Netbeans missing my point? How SHOULD I make Netbeans happy and get output to hundredths?

Comment: @DSlomer64 provide the signature of this `round` method and I could tell you if this is a Netbeans bug. I tried to reproduce this in Eclipse and Intellij and there's no such silly warning there.

Comment: I've edited the original post several times to fill in the gaps mentinoned--e.g., types of vars, `round` method in its entirety, etc. and an MCVE, which gives warning.